# IP Packet message decryption

Tags: sockets, networking, byte, packet, payload

I'm using:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
```

to get information from a network NIC on a specific IP.
I stripped the IP header and the protocol header (whether that is TCP, UDP or ICMP).

Now getting to the actual message, I already supposed this is not possible, but I'm new to network programming.

Is there a universal way to decode messages that are coming in from the byteArray?

Most people do this:

string temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packetData);

I guess assuming that the original encoding is in ASCII.

Is there a way to walk through the byte[] array of the message part and decrypt it systematically to its original value?

Or do you need to have the foreknowledge of the original encoding type and offsets?

thanks!

Comment: Are you receiving data from a server, or is this really a vague way of hinting that you are trying to parse data out of a datagram?

Comment: There is no such thing as an encoding at the level you are looking it - it is just bytes (octets). How the message is interpreted depends on the specific application protocol and maybe even higher layers, i.e. things like HTTP etc.

Comment: ahh thanks.  Sorry yes I meant the datagram or whatever the message part of the specific protocol after stripping the headers is called :)  I guess it would be pretty much akin to guessing to decrypt the specific octet (bytes) coming through...  I'm writing a sniffer application on an IP address for NIC cards and was wondering if there was a universal decipher for the messages coming through (new to networking and all).  Was wondering if there was some kind of pro-hack method to run through the byte array and decipher on that level.  Bummers.  Ah well...